# Create a log file when Visio runs?

Tags: windows

IS there anyway I can have a Windows 7 or 8 workstation create a log file when, say,  Visio runs? I want to identify when a user last ran a program.

But I don't want to use Object Access Auditing for various reasons. Thanks.

Comment: Visio 2013 does log event id 900 for Software Protection in the application log everytime it is launched.  You could attach a task to that event...but that assumes you are actually running Visio 2013 everywhere.

Comment: Or you could get silly and create Powershell script shortcuts to replace the Visio launchers in the start menu & desktop that would create a small log file (or eventlog entry) with user/datetime/whatever and then launch Visio.exe.  But Ryan is right.

Answer (score 1):

As a more generic solution for applications which do not log start times themselves, you could set up [Software Restriction Policies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh831534.aspx) or [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh994604.aspx) to allow everything and evaluate the event log for the relevant SRP-/Applocker-generated events.